# How to fix: Gradle sync failed: Unsupported method: SyncIssue.getMultiLineMessage()

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-sdk-tools, android-sdk-2.1

I'm trying to build an old app (Udacity Android Basic course, 2017) in My newest android studio (4.1.1). The old app requires:

- Android SDK v23
- Android Build Tools v23.0.2
- Android Support Repository v23.3.0

So I install android build tools v23.0.2 but I am getting a sync error every time. Please help.

> Gradle sync started
>
> 14:34  Gradle sync failed: Unsupported method: SyncIssue.getMultiLineMessage().
>           The version of Gradle you connect to does not support that method.
>           To resolve the problem you can change/upgrade the target version of Gradle you connect to.
>           Alternatively, you can ignore this exception and read other information from the model.
>           Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (17 s 149 ms)

Below is my build.gradle(:) file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

below is my gradle.wrapper.propertise file

```
#Mon Dec 28 10:00:20 PST 2015
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip
```

below is my app/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.quakereport"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
}
```

Comment: please upgrade gradle version

Comment: `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'` try this

Answer (score 0):

Changing only the classpath number didn't work for me.
But the solution I found did:

https://github.com/udacity/ud839_Miwok/issues/215#issuecomment-716142250

> I confirm the issue was fixed by making the below changes/additions in
> the following files:
>
> `build.gradle`
>
> and
>
> `gradle-wrapper.properties`
>
> In the build.gradle file I have added
>
> `maven { url 'https://maven.google.com/' name 'Google' }` in both the
> buildscript and allprojects just below jcenter() and changed the
> classpath to `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'`
>
> // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common
> to all sub-projects/modules.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    } }

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    } }

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir }
```

> and in the Gradle Properties I did the changes mentioned by @ Diver1rn and changed
> distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-all.zip

```
#Mon Dec 28 10:00:20 PST 2015
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists distr
ibutionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-all.zip
```

> Hope this helps all the others who are stuck and want to fix this
> issue with a copy and paste solution only.